# Как можно обойти/исправить <Response [403]>?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Хочу из страницы извлечь разработчика и издателя, но при GET запросе получаю 403

```
import psycopg2
import requests

url = 'https://steamdb.info/app/730'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.7.2.767 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36',
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response)
```

Comment: Сайт, который вы пытаетесь спарсить, имеет защиту от ботов (CloudFlare), которую не так просто обойти. К томуже, я не совсем понимаю, зачем вам этот сайт, если сам стим отдает все необходимое, да еще и при помощи удобного API? Вот к примеру информация об [730 игре](https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=730), в `publishers` будет издатель, а в `developers` разработчик.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну хочется человеку использовать Rust написанный на Go через Ruby, вместо C++. Пусть и использует. Или не хочет использовать токены.

Comment: Кстати, я не специалист, но возможно проблема именно в том, что вы не авторизовались?

Comment: @mister_svinia Я лишь дал альтернативу, о которой человек может даже и не знает. К чему вот ваш комментарий я не очень понимаю... И я до сих пор не вижу тут решения поставленной задачи, например в ответе дали решение с Cookie, расшифрованного CloudFlare, вот только протухнет, и решение не рабочее, а как Куку получить, что-то все молчат... Зато когда дают прям вот открытые данные, да ещё и официальный сайт а не посредник, это мы проигнорируем, да... Ну, моё дело сказать, а как с информацией поступить, дело каждого.

Comment: Первый комментарий - это я так шучу. Второй - предположение, почему произошла ошибка. Сайт точно не требует аутентификации ботов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'cf_clearance': '6YenUt_pzj120E72tLk0vj3QQjvNdLG3cR3N5tJrfws-1691757855-0-1-cffaf297.75aa331e.cac3e71-250.2.1691757855',
}
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
}
response = requests.get('https://steamdb.info/app/730/', cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
print(response)

<Response [200]>
```

или используйте селенимум